# Force application rotation even locked

Tags: ios, objective-c, rotation, orientation, cgaffinetransform

I have to develop an app that can rotate even if the device locker is on.
That's pretty simple to retrieve the current orientation from device (using `CoreMotion` or `[[UIDevice currentDevice].orientation]` with a `NSTimer`).

But now I would like to be able to make my all app rotate.

Do I have to make a transform on `visibleViewController` or is there another way much simpler ?

If I choose the first solution I have this method called at every timer step or CoreMotion refresh :

```
CGAffineTransform transform;
switch (orientation) {
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait:
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(0));
    case UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown:
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(180));
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft:
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));
    case UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight:
        transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(-90));
}

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
    self.view.window.transform = transform;
}];
```

But it works only one time.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

So I find a way to do that with transform :

```
self.view.window.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(orientationAngle, 0, 0.0, 1.0);
self.view.window.frame = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

Then I notice all my controllers and manage their frames.